# Showing / Hiding links based on criteria: React+Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having this scenario explained below:

This is pertaining to a user who can have multiple accounts.The form fields for these accounts are displayed in a card format.So on Add account, one extra card gets displayed. On Remove, the same card gets removed

1)If accounts are already there , then all should have 'Remove Account' and last one should have 'Save & add another account' button

2)If no data is present, first card should have 'save & add another account' and after addition of that account , next card should have "Save & Add another account" and then "Remove Account". Also first card should only have "Add Account"

I have written a logic, that doesn't cover all the above cases.

How can I improvise the logic?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
  addButtonClicked: boolean = false;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      accounts: [{ firstname: "", lastname: "", age: "" }]
    };
  }
  onAddAccount = (index: number) => {
    this.addButtonClicked = true;
    //adding accounts will be done here
  };

  renderAccounts = (accounts: Account[], removeButtonFlag: boolean) => {
    return accounts.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h5>
                New Account{" "}
                {this.addButtonClicked && removeButtonFlag ? (
                  <span>{index + 1}</span>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form>
              <label>First Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="firstname"
                value={value.firstname}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index)}
                required
              />
              <label>Last Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lastname"
                value={value.lastname}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index)}
              />
              <label>Age:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="age"
                value={value.age}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index)}
                required
              />
              <div>
                {this.addButtonClicked && (removeButtonFlag && index === 0) ? (
                  ""
                ) : (
                  <button onClick={() => this.onAddAccount(index)}>
                    Save & Add Another Account{" "}
                  </button>
                )}
                {removeButtonFlag && index > 0 ? <span>|</span> : ""}
                {removeButtonFlag ? (
                  <button onClick={() => this.removeAccount(index)}>
                    Remove Account
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { accounts } = this.state;
    let removeButtonFlag: boolean = false;
    if (Object.keys(accounts).length > 1) {
      removeButtonFlag = true;
    }

    return <div>{this.renderAccounts(accounts, removeButtonFlag)}</div>;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry Forgot to add it, Code has been updated @AshishKamble

Comment: @AshishKamble Yes its a number, And its a map function that iterates through accounts and then displays them. Check the code now

Comment: Thanks, i think `handleChange` saves info into state, Right

Comment: Yes handles the changes to the inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Consider dividing you solution into [components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). Card component which will display account info together with add/save/remove buttons. Props can be:

   ```
   interface IAccountCardProps {
       firstname: string, 
       lastname: string, 
       age: string,
       AddAndSave: () => void | undefined,
       Remove: () => void | undefined,
       Add: () => void | undefined
   }
   ```

`<AccountCard/>` component will get above props and will show save & add another account button if `AddAndSave` is not `undefined`. For example, first card will receive `Add` callback set (not `undefined`) and will show Add button.

`renderAccounts` may look like

```
renderAccounts = (accounts: Account[]) => {
    return accounts.length === 0 ? 
        // Return first 'default' account
        <AccountCard firstname={""}  lastname={""} age={""}
            AddAndSave={this.addAndSave.bind(this, 0)}
            Remove={undefined}
            Add={undefined}/> 
        :
        accounts.map((value, index) => {
            return <AccountCard {...value} 
                AddAndSave={accounts.length > 0 ? this.addAndSave.bind(this, index) : undefined}
                Remove={this.removeAccount.bind(this, index)}
                Add={index === 0 ? this.addAccount.bind(this, index) : undefined}/>
        })
}
```

2. All values that will change during component lifecycle should be placed in `state`. I'm talking about `removeButtonFlag`.
3. This code seems to be useless as `accounts` is array. You can better check `accounts.length`

   ```
   if (Object.keys(accounts).length > 1) {
       removeButtonFlag = true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way that the existing logic i.e. only the ternary logic could be modified?